# fecth not posting body in post request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Here is my method meant for posting login details to an external live server. this same url works when tested with postman but using fetch returns a server response 'incomplete data provided'. clearly because the body wasn't passed. what i'm i doing wrong..

```
async onRegisterPressed () {
    try {
      let response = await fetch('https://pentor-bff-ios.appspot.com/api/v1/user', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: 'badmustaofeeq@gmail.com', // this.state.email,
          password: 'password' // this.state.password
        })
      })

      let res = await response.text()
      alert('Respose from server: ' + res)
    } catch (errors) {

    }
  }
```

Comment: `'Accept': 'application/json'` looks redundant, remove that and try

Comment: Nope, didn't work..

Comment: *"clearly because the body wasn't passed."* How do you know? Did you look at the request in the network tab?

Comment: I've bn able to do a GET, problem is just with POST.. agreed 'clearly' is a little bit too definite but i've bn able to replicate those requests on postman.

Comment: `let res = await response.text()` is there any async call? Looks like you need only `response.text`

Comment: @JAG On the contrary, that can be a valuable way of checking what format the server should return.

Comment: @anoop Yes, [the Fetch API `text` function returns a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text).